# C# Consuming Java WSDL, Enum and Boolean properties don't send at request

Tags: java, c#, wcf, wsdl

I'm consuming a Java WSDL.
after filling the request object and using the request method, Enum and Boolean properties did not send with the request

After some searching I tried adding  [DataContract]/[EnumMember] attributes but the result is still the same (no success)

On the service reference.cs I did the following

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.3190.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "{some link}")]
    public enum clientSystemEnum
    {

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember()]
        /// <remarks/>
        TOP_SERVER,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember()]
        /// <remarks/>
        TOP_WEBCLIENT,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember()]
        /// <remarks/>
        TOP_IBE,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember()]
        /// <remarks/>
        SAF,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember()]
        /// <remarks/>
        EXTERNAL_SYSTEM,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember()]
        /// <remarks/>
        CCC,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember()]
        /// <remarks/>
        UNKNOWN,
    }
```

My request Object

```
doVacancyRequest.doVacancy = new doVacancy()
                {
                    vacancyRequest = new vacancyRequest()
                    {
                        pos = new pointOfSale()
                        {
                            agencyKey = "20000000",
                            clientSystem = clientSystemEnum.TOP_IBE,
                            userNumber = {my user num}
                        },
                        echotoken = "package list aa606774-f460-4404-a172-3a5a36a94eae",
                        type = serviceType.PACKAGE,
                        traveler = new traveler[]
                        {
                            new traveler(){ type = travelerType.ADULT, uid = "T1", tourOperatorPosition = 0 },
                            new traveler(){ type = travelerType.CHILD, uid = "T2", tourOperatorPosition = 0, age=6 }
                        },
                        fromDate = new DateTime(2019, 12, 08),
                        endDate = new DateTime(2019, 12, 12),
                        searchOptions = new searchOptions()
                        {
                            availableOnly = true,
                            availabilityList = true,
                            useCache = true,
                            onlyCheapest = true
                        },
                        flightSearchCriteria = new flightSearchCriteria()
                        {
                            airportFrom = "TLV",
                            airportTo = "HER"
                        },
                        packageSearchCriteria = new packageSearchCriteria()
                        {
                            loadAdditionalGeographicUnits = true,
                            loadURLs = true
                        },
                        mainOccupancy = 2,
                        extType = "P"
                    }
                };
```

and this is the xml from the fiddler

```
<vacancyRequest xmlns="">
                <pos>
                    <agencyKey>20000000</agencyKey>
                    <userNumber{my user num}</userNumber>
                </pos>
                <echotoken>package list aa606774-f460-4404-a172-3a5a36a94eae</echotoken>
                <traveler>
                    <uid>T1</uid>
                    <tourOperatorPosition>0</tourOperatorPosition>
                </traveler>
                <traveler>
                    <uid>T2</uid>
                    <tourOperatorPosition>0</tourOperatorPosition>
                </traveler>
                <flightSearchCriteria>
                    <airportFrom>TLV</airportFrom>
                    <airportTo>HER</airportTo>
                </flightSearchCriteria>
                <searchOptions />
                <extType>P</extType>
                <packageSearchCriteria />
            </vacancyRequest>
```

it can see that the enum and boolean properties did not send with the request

missing properties :
enums:

```
clientSystem = clientSystemEnum.TOP_IBE,
type = travelerType.ADULT,
type = serviceType.PACKAGE,
```

booleans:

```
packageSearchCriteria = new packageSearchCriteria()
                        {
                            loadAdditionalGeographicUnits = true,
                            loadURLs = true
                        },
 searchOptions = new searchOptions()
                        {
                            availableOnly = true,
                            availabilityList = true,
                            useCache = true,
                            onlyCheapest = true
                        },
```

Will appreciate any help,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the client proxy class to call the service?  Ordinarily, the service should automatically add these serialization items. As far as I know, only when we call the service by using Channel Factory, the client might miss some serialization items. This issue due to the items have the server namespace, which results in something wrong with type conversion. We should explicitly specify the namespace of the serialization item, like below.

```
//you should use your practical namespace to replace this value
  [DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Server1")]
    public class Product
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Color Color { get; set; }
    }
    public enum Color
    {
        Red,
        Green,
        Blue
}
```

We need not to add the data contract to Enum item since this is the default implement.
Besides, I suggest you call the service by adding service reference. it will auto generate the namespace.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exist.